# ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fc.yahoo.com', port=443) - Error attempting yfinance.Ticker(..).info

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I am trying to work with yfinance library (This is my first time attempting to work with it).

I attempted the following and it worked
`pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir`

I attempted the following in jupyter notebook and it worked

`import yfinance as yf
sp500=yf.Ticker("^GSPC")
print ("got sp500")`

I am able to see the following line printed in the jupyter notebook

`got sp500`

When I attempt the following with or without the proxy, it errors out

`sp500.proxy="http://my-proxy.org.com:xxx"
sp500.info`

I see the following error

`ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fc.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000028F3FA23590>, 'Connection to fc.yahoo.com timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))`

I am behind a proxy and I believe that this has something to do with it. Need a fix for this.

Comment: I can get that info. You can check on my kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/heinzmdsiahaan/notebook035a65e33b) . I tried without proxy. Maybe your internet connection blocked this site.

Comment: I am able to open https://finance.yahoo.com/. Should i configure a proxy?

Comment: How about ping to `fc.yahoo.com` or telnet `fc.yahoo.com` and port `443` like mentioned on error message. If can, maybe  you can try to re-install yfinance and re-run your code. If still not works, you can use kaggle like me

Comment: i get responses when i ping fc.yahoo.com. telnet is not installed in my machine :(. will try reinstalling yfinance